# Code runs differently in Pycharm and iDLE

Tags: python, pycharm, python-idle

I recently finished an assignment that requires that I need to check whether the input is a prime number. Here's the code:

```
def is_prime(num):
    check = 1
    for i in range(2,int(num/2)+1):
        if num % i==0:
            check=0
            break
    if(check):
        return (True)
    else:
        return (False)

for j in range(2,500):
    x = is_prime(j)
    if x:
        print(j)
```

I ran it in Pycharm and got all prime numbers alongside all odd numbers within the range. I ran the same code in iDLE and got just the prime numbers (which was my goal). I didn't import any libraries for either Pycharm or iDLE.

Is there something different about Pycharm that doesn't allow it to return only the prime numbers?

Comment: No, PyCharm doesn't affect how your program runs in that sense. Did you try the command-line Python interpreter too?

Comment: My guess is that the indentation was different.

Comment: I reran it multiple times and it works now. Not sure what happened but thanks for the advice!

Comment: BTW, `if` and `return` are not functions, so you can - and should - drop the parentheses. `if(check):` and `return (True)` should be `if check:` and `return True`.

Comment: Also, in your function, just use `check = False` and `check = True`, then just `return check`